# Apache 2.4 how to exclude certain GET requests from log using SetEnvIf

Tags: regex, apache, setenvif

Spent some time with docs and Google but did not find any real example for that.

I want to exclude from logging many unnecessary lines like that

```
83.266.84.27 - - [27/Oct/2018:14:07:19 -0500] "GET example.com/mod/maxtop.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3412 "http://example.com/page218.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
```

I tried

```
SetEnvIf Request_Method GET "^/maxtop\.php$" dontlog

SetEnvIf Request_Method "GET(.*)/maxtop\.php$" dontlog
```

...but no success.

Thx for any hint what else to try (if Apache GET exclude by regex at all possible...)

Comment: Maybe this works - `GET "^/mod/maxtop\.php$" dontlog` , or more general `GET ".*/maxtop\.php$" dontlog`

Comment: @Corion thx, tested, unfortunately both variants kills ALL GET requests from log, not exactly what I need...

Comment: ...just a note - I spent else more time with Google with query "apache SetEnvIf Request_Method example" - just 8-9 pages of the same poor repeating information...very strange !